# Codeigniter multi select query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have tried to make codeigniter query from mysql query

my mysql query is:

```
select * 
from class_routine 
where 
  semester='$semester' 
  and day='$day' 
  and time_schedule='$time_schedule' 
  and (batch='$batch' or section='$section' or teacher='$teacher' or room='$room');
```

for above query what will be the codeigniter query ?

I will use this query in model.

Comment: This has nothing to do with batch files. Use the correct tags next time.

Comment: Your question does not show any research done by you before asking the question -> see the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) at least.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should consider looking at the [Documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) **before** asking any question, then specify what you've looked at and what you did try, posting your code.

Anyways, try this and let me know:

```
$this->db->where(array('semester' => $semester, 'day' => $day, 'time_schedule' => $time_scehdule));
$this->db->where("batch = $batch OR section = $section OR teacher = $teacher OR room = $room", NULL, FALSE);
$result = $this->db->get('class_routine')->result();
```

When in doubt is perfectly safe to use a normal query:

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ....")->result();
```

Comment: Thanks! but it;s not working for me get error like as below:    A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR section = OR teacher = OR room =' at line 6

SELECT * FROM (`class_routine`) WHERE `semester` = '' AND `day` = '' AND `time_schedule` IS NULL AND batch = OR section = OR teacher = OR room =

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: From your error it looks like your variables ($batch etc) are empty

Comment: Mr. Web, could you please give another solution for this? I am very tired I can't get any solution.

Comment: Yes! when I use second option I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$semester' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\application\models\m_class_routine.php on line 9

Comment: Did you use double quotes? `$this->db->query("select...")`?